# Certain symbols resulting in really tall line (and cursor)

Tags: font-lock, fonts, display, symbols

This one is honestly a bit of a mystery for me.  The strange behavior is caused by the lambda symbol: the line goes to normal height if I remove the lambda.

[image]

How can I get Emacs to display such symbols correctly?

(oops, typo in the image)

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you start Emacs via `emacs -Q`? What theme are you using? Does the problem persist if you switch to a different theme (via `M-x` `load-theme`)?

Comment: +1 to @itsjeyd's comment. If the answer is no, then recursively bisect your init file, by commenting out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... until you locate the problematic part. Use command `comment-region` to comment and (with `C-u`) uncomment selected code (the active region).

Comment: Your OS and your Emacs version?

Comment: I'm on Emacs 24.4 which I run on LXDE in Ubuntu 14.04.  (Also, I updated the post; thanks all!)

Comment: Feel free to post an answer explaining your solution (changing font) and to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was...my font choice of `Inconsolata`...which makes me sad because I really liked it.

(Also, recursively bisecting the .emacs file is a great method for quickly isolating problems - thanks for the suggestion.)

**Update:**
My findings re: fonts which properly showed symbols:

- <s>Inconsolata</s> ✗
- <s>Source Code Pro</s> ✗
- Consolas ✓

(Microsoft wins this round, I suppose)